# Need help clarifying a proof ($\lim S_n=\sup S$)

Tags: analysis, proof-writing, proof-verification

Let $S$ be a bounded nonempty subset of $R$ such that $\sup S$ is not in $S$. Prove $\exists$ a sequence  $(S_n)$ of points that belong to $S$ such that $\lim S_n = \sup S$.

Let $t=\sup S$.then for each $n \in N$, $t-\frac{1}{n}$ is not an upper bound for $S$, so $\exists S_n$ satisfying $t-\frac{1}{n} < S_n < t$.

applying the squeeze theorem, let $\varepsilon > 0$. We will show that $t-\frac{1}{n} < S_n < t$ For large $n$.

since  $\lim S_n =t$,

$\exists$ $N_1$ so that $|S_nz -t| < \varepsilon$ for $n> N_1$. In particular, $n > N_1 \rightarrow (t-\frac{1}{n})-\varepsilon < S_nz$.

As $n\rightarrow \infty $, $t-\frac{1}{n}= t-0=t$.

likewise $\exists$ $N_2$ so that $|S_ny -t| < \varepsilon$ for $n> N_2$. In particular, $n>N_2\rightarrow S_ny< t+\varepsilon$.

Now let $n>\max\{N_1,N_2\} \rightarrow (t) -\varepsilon < S_nz\leq(S_n)\leq S_ny< t+\varepsilon$.

Hence $|S_n-t|<\varepsilon$

$*$ can someone help me explain this a bit more thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

You're making it a bit too complicated. Once you have your sequence of points $s_n\in S$ such that for all positive integers $n$ we have $t-\frac1n<s_n<t,$ then we can apply Squeeze Theorem directly, as the sequence of points $t-\frac1n$ and the constant sequence $t$ both converge to $t.$

I have no idea what you're doing from "We will show that" on, actually.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly start constructing a sequence S_n in which the nth element : s_n belongs to the set S such that  t - 1/n < S < t.
Now you can prove that this sequence converges to t

Comment: Welcome to Maths SE: I have reformatted your post  but the input interpretation may be wrong so in future use
 [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1) to learn how to format via $LaTeX$.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of (a part of) the answer posted **two years ago** (except that this one is badly formatted)?

Comment: Okay now that I think about it, it looks like the same idea. I think I will remove it. Thanks